# Ошибки в коде VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

Expected Expression пишет он мне в этом месте

```
oWord.Selection.InsertDateTime DateTimeFormat:="dd.MM.yyyy", InsertAsField:=True
   DateLanguage:=wdRussian, CalendarType:=wdCalendarWestern,_
   InsertAsFullWidth = False
```

Сам код может еще какие ошибки найдутся)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim kolich As Integer
kolich = 1
For Each Cell In Worksheets("Лист1").Range("a2:a500")
If (Cell.Value <> "") Then kolich = kolich + 1
Next
Dim oWord As Word.Application
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add()
oWord.Visible = True
oDoc.Activate
With oWord
oWord.Selection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
oWord.Selection.Font.Size = 16
oWord.Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
 oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:="СВИДЕТЕЛЬСТВО О ЗАКЛЮЧЕНИИ БРАКА"
    oWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
    oWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    oWord.Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
    oWord.Selection.Font.Size = 13
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:="Гражданин  "
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=TextBox1.Text
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=TextBox2.Text
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=TextBox3.Text
    oWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:="родившийся "
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=TextBox4.Text
    oWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:="месторождения г."
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=ComboBox1.Text
    oWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:="и гражданка "
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=TextBox5.Text
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=TextBox6.Text
    Selection.TypeText Text:=TextBox7.Text
    oWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:="родившаяся "
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=TextBox8.Text
    oWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:="место рождения г. "
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=ComboBox2.Text
    oWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:="заключили брак "
    oWord.Selection.InsertDateTime DateTimeFormat:="dd.MM.yyyy", InsertAsField:=True _
        , DateLanguage:=wdRussian, CalendarType:=wdCalendarWestern, _
        InsertAsFullWidth:=False
    oWord.Selection.TypeBackspace
    oWord.Selection.TypeBackspace
    oWord.Selection.InsertDateTime DateTimeFormat:="dd.MM.yyyy", InsertAsField:=True _
        , DateLanguage:=wdRussian, CalendarType:=wdCalendarWestern, _
        InsertAsFullWidth:=False
    oWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:="о чем в книге о заключении брака "
    oWord.Selection.InsertDateTime DateTimeFormat:="dd.MM.yyyy", InsertAsField:=True _
        , DateLanguage:=wdRussian, CalendarType:=wdCalendarWestern, _
        InsertAsFullWidth:=False
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=" произведена запись "
    Application.Keyboard (1033)
    Application.Keyboard (1049)
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:="№ 123"
    oWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:="После заключения брака присвоены фамилии:"
    oWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:="мужу "
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=TextBox1.Text
    oWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:="жене "
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:=TextBox1.Text
    oWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:= _
        "Подтверждаем взаимное добровольное согласие на заключение бр"
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:= _
        "ака и отсутствие обстоятельств, препятствующих заключению бр"
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:="ака."
    oWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:="Подпись мужа"
    oWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:="Подпись жены"
    oWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:="Место регистрации Дворец бракосочетания №1"
    oWord.Selection.TypeParagraph
    oWord.Selection.TypeText Text:="Дата выдачи "
    oWord.Selection.InsertDateTime DateTimeFormat:="dd.MM.yyyy", InsertAsField:=True
   DateLanguage:=wdRussian, CalendarType:=wdCalendarWestern,_
   InsertAsFullWidth = False
    End With
End Sub
```

P.S Я девушка и мне это в жизни никогда не пригодится, просто курсовая по информатике)

Comment: А зачем тогда учиться пошли? Есть хорошая фраза: Хочешь насмешить бога, расскажи ему о своих планах на завтра

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> oWord.Selection.InsertDateTime DateTimeFormat:="dd.MM.yyyy", InsertAsField:=True
>    DateLanguage:=wdRussian, CalendarType:=wdCalendarWestern,_
>    InsertAsFullWidth = False
> ```

В местах переносов строк должны стоять подчёркивания с пробелом перед ними. А тут ещё и запятая пропущена. И двоеточие. Т. е. в этих трёх строках сразу 4 ошибки. Надо так:

```
oWord.Selection.InsertDateTime DateTimeFormat:="dd.MM.yyyy", InsertAsField:=True, _
   DateLanguage:=wdRussian, CalendarType:=wdCalendarWestern, _
   InsertAsFullWidth:=False
```

Если ещё подобные ошибки есть, сама разберёшься.